# How to store button value into sessionStorage with button click on one page and add it to text input field on another page?

Tags: javascript, button, session-storage

really need help.
I have a button on page called address1.html.

```
<form action="address2.html"><a href="address2.html">
   <button class="contact-me" value="info@info.com" id="email">Contact me</button></a>
</form>
```

And I have input field on page address2.html.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="inputEmailRecipient">Email</label>
   <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmailRecipient">
</div>
```

JavaScript for page address1.html is like this:

```
function getEmail() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        let email = $(this).value();
        sessionStorage.setItem('get-email', email.value);
        return true;
    });
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    getEmail();
});
```

And for page address2.html:

```
function addEmail(){
    document.getElementById('inputEmailRecipient').innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem('get-email');
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    addEmail();
});
```

What I want to achieve is this: when I click the button on first page, the email in the value="" will be stored into sessionStorage, page is directed to address2.html and email is added into input field on that page. With current code, nothing happens and I dont get any errors in console either and I am out of ideas. I know JS very badly, this is what I came up with google and youtube.
Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Why use sessionStorage for something as simple as passing an email address? Why not pass it in the URL?

Comment: I guess I wanted something fancy and complicated :). I am not that excperienced as you can see.